# Error with scrapy item object

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am having a problem with the Scrappy item object. The current problem is that when I scrape certain fields I save them like such:

```
item['tag'] = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'video-info-row showLess')]"
                                     "//a[contains(@href, '/video/search?search')]/text()").extract()
```

There are multiple tags that get scraped with each pass and saved to item['tag']. I then go to upload the tags to my SQL server and get a mySQL syntax error. The problem is pretty obvious because it is trying to insert something like: `'tag1', u'tag2', u'tag3', u'tag4', u'tag5', u'tag6'`. Is there anyway to get rid of the quotation marks because I have tried .replace(" ' ", "") but it did not work.

Comment: BTW: you can't remove `'` because they don't exist - you have list of elements and python "print" list this way to show you that you have list of (unicode) text. You have to concatenate this elements on your own - for example like in [alecxe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [`Join()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.Join) output processor for that specific field:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    my_field = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Join(separator=','))
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on alecxe's answer, the processors only work with Item Loaders (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html):

```
def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(MyItem(), response)
    l.add_xpath('tag', '//a[@href="/video/search?search"]/text()')
    return l.load_item()
```

The other solution is to simply use the join method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['tag'] = ','.join(response.xpath('//a[@href="/video/search?search"]/text()').extract())
    return item
```